# How to make navigationItem.searchController's searchBar use the full width of the screen

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller, uinavigationitem

On iOS 11 and 12, I can't figure out a way to make the searchBar use the whole width of the screen.

```
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

I can add more margin using:

```
    let sb = searchController.searchBar
    let selector = #selector(setter: UIScrollView.contentInset)
    if sb.responds(to: selector) {
       sb.perform(selector, with: UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 0, bottom: 5, right: 35))
    }
```

If I try to set left and right to 0... it just uses the default layout.

Edit:

Getting closer:

```
    for tf in sb.subviews.first!.subviews where tf is UITextField {      
      tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      tf.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true
      tf.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

Now I am trying to figure out a way to apply constraints so that when the textfield is active, it will make space for the cancel button (UINavigationButton)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
        let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
        searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        searchBar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true
```

Here the search bar width will always equal the full width of the device's screen.

Comment: It doesn't work... Thanks to you I am getting closer though, I can apply the constraints to the UITextField subview

Now I have another problem. As I start editing, the cancel button appears and the search bar textfield doesn't resize.